# What do - and # mean in a linux file listing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

In my /var/log directory, I've got these three files (extracted from ls -l)

```
 size  filename
205198 ntp.log
  2446 ntp.log #
  4096 ntp.log -
```

The file "ntp.log -" is highlighted in blue.

What do the # and - after the names mean??

Comment: is that an `ls` output?

Comment: Yes, it's from ls -l

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smells fishy to me. Those are not characters that mean anything after the filename, which leads me to believe that they're actually part of the filename, and the entry in blue is a directory. Use `ls -lQF` to verify. You should see something like this:

```
 size  filename
205198 "ntp.log"
  2446 "ntp.log #"
  4096 "ntp.log -"/
```

Answer (score 1):

What is there in other files, if both are files. Are these similar to ntp.log

Also, You can determine the file type using '[file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file)'

```
#file <filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i can't pick a correct answer as this was migrated from stack overflow.

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:
You were correct, "ntp.log #" was a file and "ntp.log -" was a directory.
I'm not sure about "ntp.log -", but "ntp.log #" was created in my dodgy rsyslog conf file where I tried to add a comment at the end of a file path

Comment: just visit the accounts tab to associate and you can own your question.